# keys.openpgp.org keyserver fails to send confirmation mail to an Outlook-address

Tags: pgp, openpgp, key-server

I uploaded my master key's public part to the keys.openpgp.org-keyserver. It has 4 UIDs set up (4 different e-mail addresses) and each of them are correct and valid e-mail addresses.

The keyserver sent a confirmation mail to all of the e-mail addresses specified in my UIDs, but I did not receive a confirmation link on my outlook.de address. Of course, I checked junk folders etc., but there is simply nothing.

Since all other e-mail addresses could be successfully reached and thus verificated, I am now left with a certificate missing one entry - and this missing entry will likely lead to the removal of the certificate after 14 days.

Why did this happen? Is it because I altered my primary UID? Alphabetically sorted, the outlook.de-address would be the first one, but I manually overwrote this via gpg command line before submitting the  public cert to the keyserver.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it is not unusual for Microsoft Mail services (Hotmail, Outlook) to accept mails but then silently drop these if they look suspicious without any information to the sender or recipient. I don't think there is much you can do, except using a different mail provider.